How do I connect 12V WS2811 LED's to Raspberry Pi (I accidentally bought a 5V power source)
I realized later that I bought 12V LED's instead of 5V LED's.
So I bought a 5V power source and a 74AHCT125 - Quad Level-Shifter (3V to 5V) so I could connect the LED's to the pi.
My question is will this still work or should I buy new stuff?
I'm following this guide

Second question:
The LED's have a Xconnect type connector. To connect them to the pi should I just cut the female connector of and use the wires to connect them to the pins?

you require a 12 V power supply to light the LEDs ... the LEDs can probably be controlled with a 5 V signal, check the datasheet

This stuff is completely new to me. The LED's don't really have a datasheet that I can find. Could you maybe recommend me some resources to learn about this?

Regarding the data to control the LEDs, have you looked into how well a SBC can create time sensitive data strings? Since most SBC run dozens of programs simultaneously, they can struggle to create time sensitive signals. Addressable LEDs might do unexpected things and servo motors might jitter. I think there are ways to mitigate these problems. But leaving this comment just so you aware of the possibilities.

Do some research! There are plenty of guides online. Just search for something like, 'LED voltage' or 'LED tutorial'.
